# Convert midi to mp3 in node

Tags: node.js

So im developing an app in node where i use [scribbletune](https://github.com/scribbletune/scribbletune)

To create a midi-file:

```
const clip = scribble.clip({
  notes: cMajor,
  pattern: 'xxxxxxx'
});

scribble.midi(clip, 'c-major.mid');
```

I want to be able to play this file in the browser.
From what i gather there is no way to play midi in the browser using audio-tags:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

So im thinking that i should first convert the midi-file into an mp3-file. I've been searching the web for a node-package that could do this but have not found anything.

It sounds like something that should be possible.

Any tips on how to achieve this in node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to play the generated MIDI in the browser and converting the file to **ogg** first and playing it using an audio tag is not a requirement, [**MidiConvert**](https://github.com/Tonejs/MidiConvert) and [**Tone.js**](https://github.com/Tonejs/Tone.js) (as briefly explained in [**Scribbletune**](https://github.com/scribbletune/scribbletune#install) docs) can do the job.

I've hacked together an example:

```
const http = require("http");

const MidiConvert = require("midiconvert"); // npm install midiconvert
const scribble = require("scribbletune"); // npm install scribbletune

const createMidiForToneJs = (notes, pattern) => {
  let clip = scribble.clip({
    notes,
    pattern
  });

  let midiData;

  // The callback is called synchronously (https://github.com/scribbletune/scribbletune/blob/ebda52d7a2835f28b3ddab15488c22bc1d425e7b/src/midi.js#L37)
  scribble.midi(
    clip,
    null, // setting filename to null will cause this method to return bytes (via the callback)
    (err, bytes) => {
      // err is always null
      midiData = bytes;
    }
  );

  return MidiConvert.parse(midiData);
};

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  // Don't mind the naivety of the following URL router
  switch (req.url.toLowerCase()) {
    case "/":
      res.end(indexHTMLContents);
      break;
    case "/midi.json":
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      const jsonString = JSON.stringify(createMidiForToneJs("CM", "xxxxxxx"));
      res.end(jsonString);
      break;
    default:
      res.statusCode = 404;
      res.end();
  }
});

server.listen(3000); // Open http://localhost:3000 in browser

// -- The HTML and Javascript for the "/" route. Obviously, don't do this in production!

const jsToBeExecutedInBrowser = () => {
  document.querySelector("button").addEventListener(
    "click",
    async () => {
      Tone.Transport.clear();
      Tone.Transport.stop();

      const synth = new Tone.Synth().toMaster();

      const response = await fetch("/midi.json");
      const midiJson = await response.json();

      const midi = MidiConvert.fromJSON(midiJson);

      Tone.Transport.bpm.value = midi.bpm;
      Tone.Transport.timeSignature = midi.timeSignature;

      midi.tracks.forEach(track => {
        new Tone.Part((time, event) => {
          synth.triggerAttackRelease(
            event.name,
            event.duration,
            time,
            event.velocity
          );
        }, track.notes).start(midi.startTime);
      });

      Tone.Transport.start();
    },
    false
  );
};

const indexHTMLContents = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Midi Player</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <button>Play!</button>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tone"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/midiconvert"></script>
  <script>
  (${jsToBeExecutedInBrowser.toString()})();
  </script>
  </body>
</html>`;
```

Comment: While this is a good solution to their specific problem... future folks will land here looking for a midi to mp3 node solution.